# MongoDB Deprecation Warning

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mern

As I'm super new in the (MERN) technology. This warning is quite bugging me for some time
(DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated.)
And I'm not using any on this fucntion either.

```
router.delete('/:id', (req, res)=> {
    Category.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).then(category => {
        if(category){
            return res.status(200).json({success: true, message: ' The category is deleted...'})
        } else {
            return res.status(404).json({success: false, message: " Category not found..."})
        }
    }).catch(err=>{
        return res.status(404).json({success: false, error: err})
    })
})
```

The warning shows up when I use Delete method on postman...

Comment: Have you tried `findOneAndDelete(id)`?

Answer (score 1):

> If you use Model.findOneAndUpdate(), by default you'll see one of the below deprecation warnings[...]
> This option affects the following model and query functions.
> Model.findByIdAndDelete()
> Model.findByIdAndRemove()
> Model.findByIdAndUpdate()
> Model.findOneAndDelete()
> Model.findOneAndRemove()
> Model.findOneAndUpdate()
> Query.findOneAndDelete()
> Query.findOneAndRemove()
> Query.findOneAndUpdate()

Most of the time some mongoose commands are just aliases for MongoDB commands.

The solution is simple, you must pass the options to the mongoose connection:

```
mongoose.connect(uri, { useFindAndModify: false });
```

Or set it after:

```
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

More info at: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html (findAndModify())

Comment: Really appreciated ^^ and specially for telling where to put it..

Answer (score 0):

just add `mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);`